# what is the best number of segment per download for xdman?

Tags: 14.04, downloads

I have terrible internat connection (about 15KB/sec --while download),the `xdman` package allows the user to select the number of segment per download.
is this setting depends on the quality of connection(faster or slower)

Answer (score 2):

`wget --continue` will download the file in multiple tries, if necessary. No need to "segment". `sudo apt-get install wget; man wget`. Then, you would do:

```
wget --<wget options> --continue https://somesite.example.org/reallybigfile
```

Repeat until done. The first time, `--continue` is ignored, and `wget` starts downloading. Network connection drops, `wget` times out. The second (and subsequent) tries, `--continue` tells `wget` to resume downloading the file where it left off. Eventually, the download will complete, and the whole file will be there.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal segment size is either 4 or 8
Try with both4 and 8 segment and compare the speed

Comment: When you have 15KB/s segments will not help much...  Retries is what needs to be set like the other answer.